# What do you call a sentence that is not narrative or non-narrative?

Tags: grammar, narration

I am not sure if I framed the question right. I will explain, say I have two sentences that describe services provided by a company as below:

1. We provide good quality of service.
2. 1-year warranty on all moving parts.

As per my understanding, the first sentence is `narrative` and first-person point of view. However the second sentence is different, it is not `narrative` as per my limited understanding. So I looked up if its `non-narrative`. But as per information found online `Non-narrative` writing is almost always written from the third-person point of view would opt for "he," "she" and "they" statements.

So if the second sentence is not narrative and non-narrative, what you call such sentences that do not use `I`,`We`,`He` or `She` kind of statements?

Comment: "2." is not a sentence in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes the second sentence special is the lack of any verb. In linguistics, this is referred to as a *zero copula*, but generally native English speakers understand this as the abbreviated language of headlines and simple lists. Nevertheless, there *is* an implied verb, and in the context of the first statement, an implied subject as well (*we*).

> [We provide a] 1-year warranty on all moving parts.

For the record, talking about narrative and non-narrative forms makes much more sense in the context of a story vs. a list of services.

And, regarding your question about sentences without pronouns, I think what you are referring to are sentences in the **passive voice**.

In the active voice:

> 1. We provide a 1-year warranty on all moving parts.

And in the passive voice:

> 2. A 1-year warranty is provided on all moving parts.

Comment: That makes it clear. Your way of answering is really good and made it super easy for me to grasp.